# how to insert a checkbox in a list

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, listadapter

I have this list ... I should put a check box as the last element (where the word "notification") ... I do not know how to do .. because each element has its own icon ... but the last I've got to put a checkbox ....

[image]

```
enter code here
```

public class Listview extends Activity {

```
protected static final Intent CopyOfListview = null;
static ListView listView;


static public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<Void, Person, Void> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute () {
        // Prima di iniziare a inserire gli elementi svuotiamo l'adapter
        ( ( ArrayAdapter<Person> ) listView.getAdapter() ).clear();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground ( Void... params ) {

        // Qui dentro si possono mettere le operazioni che potrebbero
        // rallentare il caricamento della listview, come ad sempio il
        // caricamento da db degli oggetti

        Person[] people = { new Person( " Privacy",null, R.drawable.freccetta ) };
        Person[] people1 = {new Person( " Visualizzazione", null, R.drawable.freccetta )};
        Person[] people2=  { new Person( " Notifiche", null, R.drawable.freccetta)};

        // riempimento casuale della lista delle persone
        Random r = new Random();

        for ( int i = 0; i < 1; i++ ) {
            // Pubblichiamo il progresso
            publishProgress( people);
            publishProgress( people1);
            publishProgress( people2);

        }

        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate ( Person... values ) {
        // Aggiungiamo il progresso pubblicato all'adapter
        ( ( ArrayAdapter<Person> ) listView.getAdapter() ).add( values[0] );
        super.onProgressUpdate( values );
    }

}

@Override
public void onCreate ( final Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView( R.layout.main );


    listView = ( ListView ) findViewById( R.id.personListView );

    listView.setAdapter( new PersonAdapter( this, R.layout.row_item, new ArrayList<Person>() ) );

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Person p = (Person) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            switch(position) {
            case 0:
                Activity_privacy();
            //  startActivity(CopyOfListview);
                //onCreate1(savedInstanceState);
//  setContentView(R.layout.main1);
            break;
            case 1:
            setContentView(R.layout.main2);
            break;
            case 2:
            setContentView(R.layout.main3);
            }
            }
    });

    new BackgroundWorker().execute();
}


protected void Activity_privacy()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, CopyOfListview.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason adding a [footer view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29) wouldn't work?

If for some reason that's not an acceptable solution, the only other thing I can think of is to create a custom class that implements the [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) interface. It will have to return two different view types (i.e. `getViewTypeCount()` will return 2) and returns different views from `getView()` based on the position you're requesting the view for.

Answer (score 0):

Have your PersonAdapter class return the button view when getView is called for the last element of the list. Be sure that getCount returns the correct size when you do this.

You may also benefit from having the adapter take a collection of view factories instead of List<Person>.